# Can't output Python Print in PHP

Tags: php, python, linux

I'm really stuck on this one, but I am a python (and Raspberry Pi) newbie. All I want is to output the `print` output from my python script. The problem is (I believe) that a function in my python script takes half a second to execute and PHP misses the output.

This is my php script:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$cmd = escapeshellcmd('/var/www/html/weathertest.py');
$output = shell_exec($cmd);
echo $output;

//$handle = popen('/var/www/html/weathertest.py', 'r');
//$output = fread($handle, 1024);
//var_dump($output);
//pclose($handle);

//$cmd = "python /var/www/html/weathertest.py";
//$var1 = system($cmd);
//echo $var1;

echo 'end';
?>
```

I've included the commented blocks to show what else I've tried. All three output "static text end"

This is the python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import Adafruit_DHT
import time

print 'static text '

humidity, temperature = Adafruit_DHT.read(11, 4)

time.sleep(3)

print 'Temp: {0:0.1f}C Humidity: {1:0.1f}%'.format(temperature, humidity)
```

The py executes fine on the command line. I've added the 3 second delay to make the script feel longer for my own testing.

Given that I always get `static text` as an output, I figure my problem is with PHP not waiting for the Adafruit command. BUT the STRANGEST thing for me is that all three of my PHP attempts work correctly if I execute the PHP script on the command line i.e. `php /var/www/html/test.php` - I then get the desired output:

```
static text
Temp: 23.0C Humidity 34.0%
end
```

So I guess there's two questions: 1. How to make PHP wait for Python completion. 2. Why does the PHP command line differ from the browser?

Comment: What is the `shell_exec` returning in the error case? Try to use `var_dump($output)` instead of `echo $output` to figure it out

Comment: Marco - there is no error, PHP in the browser gives me the first line "static text" but not the next one. PHP in the command line gives both. Using var_dump, the browser gives me string(12) and the command gives me the complete string(40)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. How to make PHP wait for Python completion

`shell_exec` will wait the command to finish

> 2. Why does the PHP command line differ from the browser?

My best guess is the difference of the user running the command. On the command line the script is running as the same user you're logged in, on the "browser", probably as the same user as apache/nginx, the environment variables are different on both cases.

---

Add `python` before the script, i.e.:

```
$output = shell_exec("python /var/www/html/weathertest.py");
echo $output;
```

Or use the `fullpath` to the python binary:

```
$output = shell_exec("/full/path/to/python /var/www/html/weathertest.py");
echo $output;
```

---

PS: To know the `fullpath` use `which python` on the shell.

Comment: Why do you think this makes a difference? If there's a shebang (which I think there is), the shell spawned should not have problem at all. Further, the OP's problem is that only the first line is being read, as opposed to entire stdout.

Comment: Pedro Lobito: SuperSaiyan is right, I have no issues with executing the script, I just need the script within php to execute synchronously.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer, but added info to show why Pedro Lobito is correct.

I edited my Python script to be:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import Adafruit_DHT
import time

print 'static text '

# humidity, temperature = Adafruit_DHT.read(11, 4)

time.sleep(10)

# print 'Temp: {0:0.1f}C Humidity: {1:0.1f}%'.format(temperature, humidity)

print "waited 10 seconds"
```

You will notice I simply commented out my problem areas, increased the sleep to 10 seconds and then added a new print at then end. Running this in the browser now takes a while - 10 seconds - so the script is waiting completion.

My problem is now with `Adafruit_DHT.read` so I will investigate separately.

**EDIT (a few hours later with a fresh mind):**
My problem was not with that module or function, my problem was with permissions of the third-party module (Adafruit_DHT) which I installed. Pedro's answer to my question about the difference between php in the browser and the command line was the key. I thought apache was running as root, but after looking at the config with `sudo nano /etc/apache2/envvars`, I saw it was www-data. I changed it to me, and my script worked perfectly in the browser. Obviously, apache running as me is not great, but at least I could prove the problem was permissions on that particular module!